# Given a real number what is the minimum number of times it can be tetrated to get an intiger?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers, tetration

I really enjoyed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdHFLfv-ThQ) on the possibility that $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ is an integer, but i thought that it was a case of a more interesting  general problem.

Given a real $x$ and an integer $y$, what is the minimum non-zero integer $y$ such that the tower $x↑↑y$ is an integer; where $↑↑$ represents [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) (i.e. repeated exponentiation)?

Its clear that for integers $y=1$; and that for the $n$th root of a multiple of $n, y$ is at most $n+1$. For what other real numbers can we obtain $y$?
Should we expect $y$ to exist for all real numbers?

Comment: Please, get a grip. The reason why tetration is what it is, an exotic notion prone to enthusiastic upvotes at MSE, is exactly that. It's exotic because nobody ever was able to find any reasonable use for it, so it stayed outside of textbooks, and nowadays, even outside of most wannabe educational videos at youtube.

Comment: @NoNames Like you, I don't recall seeing a reasonable use for tetration. But I also don't recall seeing a reasonable use for twin primes. That doesn't make me disparage work on the twin prime conjecture. As for the present question, it could be a useful exercise for students to prove that, for any fixed positive integer $y$, $x\uparrow\uparrow y$ is an increasing function of $x$ for $x>0$, and therefore the OP's hoped-for $y$ usually doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andreas Blass My bad, I should have made more precise "use": inspiring *any* further leading idea in mathematics.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm really sorry - I don't quite follow what you've said. Intuitively it makes sense if y generally doesn't exist, but i don't see how proving x↑↑y is an increasing function would help prove that (unless the intigers were a set with a finite upper bound).

Comment: For each integer $n$ and each integer $y$, there can be only one $x$ such that $x\uparrow\uparrow y=n$. There are only countably many pairs $(n,y)$ of integers, so only countably many values of $x$ will have a $y$ for which $x\uparrow\uparrow y$ is an integer.

Comment: That's rather lovely! thanks!